# i want to know in how many table the data existing in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i need sql  script to check,from a database  how many table have  data and how many table is empty??

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please list some of the tables involved.  Please show us what code you have tried and the full text of any error messages it produces.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information on how to ask a good Question.

Comment: i need to know howmany table have data from a databse.I have a database with morethan 100 table but in that there is no data in some of the table , i need to know how many table contain data

Comment: Just use the standard reports in SSMS, "Disc usage by top xxx tables"

Comment: can you give an example for this James

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
USE dbName
SELECT COUNT(*) from information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_type = 'base table'
```

Comment: this is not what i expect

Answer (score 0):

AS Suggested by @ James Z in the comments you can use the standard reports in SSMS.
    **Right Click** on the `Database` instance

> REPORTS-->STANDARD REPORTS-->DISK USAGE BY TABLES

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE EmptyFullTableCounter AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fldNameValue VARCHAR( 64 );
    DECLARE @sqlStatementString varchar( 200 );

    DECLARE @loopIndex INT = 1;
    DECLARE @recordCount INT;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempTblTableNames;

    CREATE TABLE tempTblTableNames
    (
        fldName    VARCHAR( 64 ),
        fldCount   INT
    );

    INSERT INTO tempTblTableNames ( fldName,
                                    fldCount )
    SELECT table_name,
           0
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
      AND table_catalog = 'UserAccessAccounts001'
      AND table_name != 'tempTblTableNames';

    SET @recordCount = ( SELECT COUNT( * )
                         FROM tempTblTableNames );

    WHILE @loopIndex <= @recordCount
        BEGIN
            SET @fldNameValue = ( SELECT fldName
                                  FROM ( SELECT fldName,
                                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY fldName ) AS recordNumber
                                         FROM ( SELECT fldName
                                                FROM tempTblTableNames
                                              ) AS fldNamesFinder
                                       ) AS fldNamesWithRowNumber
                                  WHERE recordNumber = @loopIndex );

            SET @sqlStatementString = 'UPDATE tempTblTableNames ' +
                                      'SET fldCount = ( SELECT COUNT( * ) ' +
                                      '                 FROM ' +
                                      @fldNameValue +
                                      ' ) ' +
                                      'WHERE fldName = ''' +
                                      @fldNameValue +
                                      ''';';

            EXEC ( @sqlStatementString );

            SET @loopIndex = @loopIndex + 1;
        END

    SELECT SUM( IIF( fldCount > 0, 1, 0 ) ) AS Haves,
           SUM( IIF( fldCount = 0, 1, 0 ) ) AS HaveNots
    FROM tempTblTableNames;

    DROP TABLE tempTblTableNames;
END
```

This procedure starts by creating a table to hold the names of each table, then populates it using the following statement...

```
INSERT INTO tempTblTableNames ( fldName,
                                fldCount )
SELECT table_name,
       0
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND table_catalog = 'UserAccessAccounts001'
  AND table_name != 'tempTblTableNames';
```

Please note that the above statement excludes `tempTblTableNames` from our list of tables.

The procedure then stores a count of the total number of records in the variable `@recordCount`.  This value is used as a sentinel value for a `WHILE` loop that extracts each table name from `tempTblTableNames` and constructs around it a statement that will update that table name's associated count in `tempTblTableNames`.  This statement is then executed and the loop index iterated.

Once the loop has completed a final `SELECT` statement is performed that uses `SUM()` in conjunction with `IIF()` to count the number of tables that have records and the number of tables that do not have records.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.